# Subset dataframe in r for a specific month and date

Tags: r, dataframe, time, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 Month_nr Date
 1 2   3  1  2017-01-01
 3 5   6  1  2017-01-02
 6 8   9  2  2017-02-01
 6 8   9  8  2017-08-01
```

and I want to take all variables from the data set that have Month=1 (January) and date from 2017-01-01 til 2017-01-31 (so end of January), which means that I want to take the dates as well. I would create a column with days but I have multiple observations for one day and this would be even more confusing. I tried it with this:

```
df<- filter(df,df$Month_nr == 1, df$Date > 2017-01-01 && df$Date < 2017-01-31)
```

but it did not work. I would appreciate so much your help! I am desperate at this point. My dataset has measurements for an entire year (from 1 to 12) and hence I filter for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't put quotation marks around 2017-01-01. Directly putting 2017-01-01 will compute the subtraction and return a number, and then you're comparing a string to a number. You can compare string to string; with string, "2" is still greater than "1", so it would work for comparing dates as strings. BTW, you don't need to write `df$` when using `filter`; you can directly write the column names without quoting when using the tidyverse.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response. The class is factor. I want to ask how the entire command would then look like? Sorry, I am very new to R and still learning.

Comment: `df<- filter(df, Month_nr == 1, Date > "2017-01-01" & Date < "2017-01-31")`

Comment: BTW, don't use `&&` in filter, and use `&` instead. `&&` and `||` are only used in `if` statements and do short circuit evaluation. `&` compared two vectors element wise, while `&&` only compares the first element of two vectors.

Comment: Many thanks! I just tried it and I get: `Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(Date, "2017-01-01") : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(Date, "2017-01-31") : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: I see. I also often forget about this. You should convert the `Date` column into character by `df <- df %>% mutate(Date = as.character(Date))`. Then you can compare. Another thing to note, when you construct a data frame by `data.frame`, remember to put argument `stringsAsFactor = FALSE` to prevent R from converting strings into factors. Or you can use `tibble` when constructing data frames

Comment: Just converted it to as.date since it was a factor. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh okay, I see! Thank you again! :D Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have the month as well as dates in the filter? Just the filter on the dates would work fine. However, you will have to convert the date column into a date object. You can do that as follows:

```
df$Date_nr <- as.Date(df$Date_nr, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df_new <- subset(df, Date_nr >= "2017-01-01" & Date_nr <= "2017-01-31")
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response. I forgot to mention, but I am filtering for month==1 because I have data for an entire year and many more months. I would appreciate if you could help me subsetting it by month and date at the same time. Thank you

Comment: I meant that by filtering for range of dates, wouldn't the month be taken care of?
Ex. In this case you are filtering for Dates lying in between Jan 1 and Jan 31 and hence by default you have the month = 1 condition being satisfied

Comment: Keeping the month = 1 condition in the subset will create a problem if ever your date range changes and is including dates from more than 1 month